# Replace a fixed value with a variable in a text file with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I want to replace `OLD` with `%NEW%` in `test.txt` by using a batch file:

```
@echo off 
set /p NEW=""
set InputFile=test.txt
find OLD
replace %NEW%
```

my test.txt contains various characters like `~` `:` `;` `_` `.`which I attribute to various solutions clapping out.

I have attempted to use [BatchSubstitude.bat](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace) to achieve this but it does not "find" `OLD` and does not replace any text.

I have also attempted to use [fart.exe](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) but I receieve an error when trying to perform this:

```
find_string="OLD"
replace_string="test"
actual find_length=3
actual replace_length=4
processing \filepath\,test.txt
skipping binary file: \filepath\test.txt
```

The documentation for this is sparse and nothing I could google furiously would provide a solution.

The reason I am using batch for the moment is that I perform various windows CE  actions such as cecopy, pdel and rapistart for windows CE deployment over activesync and batch seems to be the easiest way to to get the result that I am after - and I'm a total noob at batch.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved with batch and perhaps explain how the various functions work to achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@set @a=0  /*

@echo off 
set /p NEW=""
set InputFile=test.txt
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%NEW%" < "%InputFile%" > output.tmp
move /Y output.tmp "%InputFile%"

@goto :EOF */

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(/OLD/g,WScript.Arguments(0)));
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Short and sweet, too! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Do not download anything from [sourceforge](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/sourceforge-grabs-gimp-for-windows-account-wraps-installer-in-bundle-pushing-adware/) so better to skip fart-it.
The method in the dostips is not so robust when special characters are used (`&<>|^`) as it is pointed there.Here's a simple batch/jscript that will replace a content in a file (you can change the hardcoded things like file location):

```
0</* :
@echo off

set "file=c:\test.txt"
set "find=OLD"
set /p "replace=NEW: "
cscript /nologo /E:jscript "%~f0" %file% %find% %replace%

echo ==replaced==


exit /b */0;

var FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
if (ARGS.Length < 3 ) {
 WScript.Echo("Wrong arguments");
 WScript.Quit(1);
}
var filename=ARGS.Item(0);
var find=ARGS.Item(1);
var replace=ARGS.Item(2);

var readStream=FSOObj.OpenTextFile(filename, 1);

var content=readStream.ReadAll();
readStream.Close();

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

var newConten=replaceAll(find,replace,content);

var writeStream=FSOObj.OpenTextFile(filename, 2);
writeStream.WriteLine(newConten);
writeStream.Close();
```

Check also this more advanced tools

[FindRepl](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697&start=60)

[JRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044)

Comment: I'm not sure why but the solution doesn't replace the string and I do not receive any prompts, adding in a pause gives me this: `Microsoft JScript runtime error: File not found` `==Replaced==` even though the file is clearly in the path specified and the text file is not modified.

Comment: @CallumVine - change the location here ` set "file=c:\test.txt"`  to the actual one - you can also use set /p